# How to make a Post SOAP request with XML fields in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, xml, rest, soap, restsharp

The fields are in `XML` format.

Which is the code that I need in order to make `SOAP` Request in RestSharp?

And with `HttpClient` also?

For example how to write the below code in RestSharp and `HttpClient` also?

```
POST /Folder.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org">
  <soap:Body>
    <MainFolder xmlns="Url">
      <User>string</User>
      <Pass>string</Pass>     
      <Folder>
        <Field1>string</Field1>
        <Field2>string</Field2>     
      </Folder>
    </MainFolder >
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For example I have written something like this.

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient("Url");

RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("Url?wsdl", Method.POST);

restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "text/xml");

restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

restRequest.AddXmlBody("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org">"
                           + " <soap:Body> "
                              + "<MainFolder xmlns=\"Url">"
                                  + "<Username>string</Username>"
                                  + "<Password>string</Password>"                   
                                  + "<Folder>"
                                     + "<Field1>string</Field1>"
                                     + "<Field2>string</Field2>"
                                  + "</Folder>"
                               + "</MainFolder>"
                            + "</soap:Body>"
                      + "</soap:Envelope>");

IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

How to write this in the right way and also how to write this in `HttpClient` also?

Comment: RestSharp is only a library and not the server.  Each server has its own requirements.  The fields are determined by the server, not the library.

Comment: Please give some more information about: What have you tried so far? How does your code looks like and what is your exact problem? We are all willing to help you in case you face an issue but we are not willing to write your complete code.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the web of creating a SOAP.  You need to read the documentation on the server you are using to get the specific parameters that need to be set to work with the server.

Comment: Exactly!!!  Each Server has different requirements (parameters) and without knowing the specifics it is hard to solve.  Normally I recommend first using a vendor app that works and then use a sniffer to compare the working SOAP with the one not working.

Comment: Could anyone write some code in order to check the different point of views.